# Lookback with NA handling

Tags: r, time-series

I have some data that has date, id, and value.  I would like to add a column called "bad_perf", where this looks, by id, today and the previous two day's values, then assigns a 1 when all 2 days are less than 10.  If today's data is an NA, assign a 0.  If the previous 2 days have an NA, assign a 0.  If it runs out of data, assign an 0.

Here's the data:

```
asof_dt<-mdy("11/14/2014","11/21/2014","11/28/2014","12/5/2014","4/25/2014","5/2/2014","5/9/2014","5/16/2014","5/23/2014","5/30/2014","6/6/2014")
  id<-c("ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","XYZ","XYZ","XYZ","XYZ","XYZ","XYZ","XYZ")
  value<-c(7,8,3,10,11,10,1,NA,9,3,10)
  df<-data.frame(asof_dt,id,value)   


> df
     asof_dt  id value
1  2014-11-14 ABC     7
2  2014-11-21 ABC     8
3  2014-11-28 ABC     3
4  2014-12-05 ABC    10
5  2014-04-25 XYZ    11
6  2014-05-02 XYZ    10
7  2014-05-09 XYZ     1
8  2014-05-16 XYZ    NA
9  2014-05-23 XYZ     9
10 2014-05-30 XYZ     3
11 2014-06-06 XYZ    10
```

Here's my desired outcome with my comment in line to hopefully bring more clarity.

```
        asof_dt  id value   bad_perf    Comment
  11/14/2014    ABC 7   0   Assigned 0; not enough data
  11/21/2014    ABC 8   0   Assigned 0; not enough data
  11/28/2014    ABC 3   1   Assigned 1; this record and the previous 2 records are less than or equal to 
  12/5/2014     ABC 10  1   Assigned 1; this record and the previous 2 records are less than or equal to 
  4/25/2014     XYZ 11  0   Assigned 0; not enough data
  5/2/2014      XYZ 10  0   Assigned 0; not enough data
  5/9/2014      XYZ 1   0   Assigned 0; previous 2 records are not less than or equal to 10
  5/16/2014     XYZ NA  0   Assigned 0; current value is NA
  5/23/2014     XYZ 9   0   Assigned 0; at least 1 NA
  5/30/2014     XYZ 3   0   Assigned 0; at least 1 NA
  6/6/2014      XYZ 10  1   Assigned 1; this record and the previous 2 records are less than or equal to
```

Unfortunately, not sure how to get started.  I do this step in Excel right now!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `base R` methods (`embed`) to create the "lags" after splitting the "value" column by "id".  Then check whether all the elements in each row are less than 10 (`rowSums(...)`), `unlist` and get the index.

```
df$bad_perf <- unlist(sapply(split(df$value, df$id), function(x) {
               x1 <-embed(c(rep(NA,2), x), 2)
          as.numeric(rowSums(cbind(x, x1[-nrow(x1),])<=10, na.rm=TRUE)==3)
           }), use.names=FALSE)
```

Or you could use the devel version of data.table, which introduced the function `shift` to get the "lag" columns, and do the `rowSums` as in the previous solution.

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.9.5
df1 <- copy(df) 
df1$bad_perf <- setDT(df)[,shift(value, n=0:2L) , id][,
                 (rowSums(.SD<=10, na.rm=TRUE)==3)+0L,.SDcols=2:4][]
```

Or using `dplyr`, the lag columns can be generated.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
          group_by(id) %>% 
          mutate(value1=lag(value), value2=lag(value, 2L))

df$bad_perf <- (rowSums(df1[3:5]<=10, na.rm=TRUE)==3)+0
df$bad_perf
#[1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Talk about genius...wow thank you!  I am using the last one because it's very easy to understand the logic.  What is the logic of using the +0 at the end?

Comment: @TrexionKameha  Glad that it helped you.  When we add 0, it coerces the logical vector to binary.  Otherwise, you have to use `as.numeric(` as in the first case.